# Stackdriver Logging is not handling correctly python quit(code) stack trace in Google Cloud Function, any alternative ?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, stackdriver, python-3.7, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have a google cloud function written in python37, for some conditions I log an error (using logging) and then use quit(code) to put an end to the function execution.
The error logging is logged properly in stackdriver. The problem is how stackdriver handle the quit(). It will log every line in the stacktrace as a log entry for handling as you can see in the capture. The same thing happens when I use sys.exit(code) or raise SystemExit(code).
Finally the cloud functions exits with 0 as if no error was there.
Any one have an alternative to stop the cloud function after an error ? then any explanation about stackdriver behaviour would be great.

Thx!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue thanks to this tweet : how lucky ! https://twitter.com/iamdevloper/status/1060067235316809729

The solution was in the docs here : https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/error-reporting

and using : raise RuntimeError('I failed you') solved my issue. Very good lesson and reminder :)